# htaccess redirect on specific subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Ok, I am working on a large collaborative project with a handful of people, and we are using SVN. So we have subdomains for each person acting as a repo for each person. With that, we have started to addon a new feature, well a couple of us have, of which requires the files from the repo. Its not a trunk/branch type of thing either.

Anyway enough pretense, what I want to do is take sub1.domain.com and make it automatically use another folder outside of root as the default loading directory. So I am wondering if this is even possible to be specific with a subdomain and htaccess for this cause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  sub.example.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [P]
```